# qplot Break Formating in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am using Knitr to echo my results. In the for loop, I subset and print according to a numeric code. The issue arises when I add another argument for the scale. The years begin to clump together. + scale_x_continuous(breaks(...)) works when outside the loop.

```
for( i in unique(cdata$temp)) {
 i<- cdata[cdata$temp== i,]
 my.plot<-qplot(i$Year,
   i$Consumption,
   main =paste0("Consumption  ", prettyNum(i, ",")),
   xlab = "Year",
   ylab = "Consumption (kcal)")
+scale_x_continuous(breaks =paste0(seq(2010, 2100, by=10))))

print(my.plot)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few strange things in your code, and I'm not sure which is causing your problem, but here's a working equivalent:

```
for(i in unique(cdata$temp)) {

    cdata_i <- cdata[cdata$temp == i, ]

    my.plot <- ggplot(cdata_i, aes(x = Year, y = Consumption)) +
                   geom_point() +
                   labs(x = "Year",
                        y = "Consumption (kcal)",
                        title = paste("Consumption:", prettyNum(i, ","))) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2010, 2100, by = 10))

    print(my.plot)

}
```

A few suggestions:

- Don't overwrite `i` within the loop - `i` is useful (I use it to make the titles below)
- Use the function `ggplot` instead of `qplot`. `qplot` is fine for quick, interactive plots, but as soon as you're trying to do something more complex (like this), using `ggplot` will save you a lot of headaches.
- Use the `limits` argument of `scale_x_continuous` to make sure that your plots all have the same `x` axis. Setting `breaks` alone won't guarantee that 2010 and 2100 appear on every plot.